# Can I convert and deconvert a bache0 device to a standard block device and still read the filesystem?

Tags: raid, bcache

When I set my raid (ex. /dev/md0) as a backing device.  To work with the raid device, I have to interface with /dev/bcache0.

However, if I wanted to add to the raid using mdadm, I need to address /dev/md0 and other /dev/ devices to add to it.

Won't I destroy my bcache superblock information if I add devices to /dev/md0?

Is there anyway for bcache to work with an underlying filesystem without having to work with /dev/bcache0 as a new filesystem?  If I create a filesystem on /dev/md0 and then setup /dev/md0 as a backing device, /dev/bcache0 does not have the same filesystem.  I have to setup a new filesystem.

This is kind of a bummer with raid6.  If I wish to add new devices, I don't believe I'm going to be able to if the underlying is a bcache.

Comment: Could you clarify—do you mean add new devices, resizing the RAID array, or add new devices as spares or to replace a failed drive, but leaving the array size the same?